# how to edit the qt .pro file for debug and release modes for opencv in c++

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt-creator

opencv c++ works fine but im checking if its running the opencv release and debug lib files. they seem to give me the same 20fps in release and debug (im testing by checking the fps of my camera video in opencv) is there a better way to test this? and is my .pro file correct?

opencv was built from source using vs, this is my .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += E:\\buildsfullsize\\cvbuild\\install\\include

debug {
LIBS +=-LE:\\buildsfullsize\\cvbuild\\install\\x64\\vc16\\lib \
    -lopencv_aruco430d \
    -lopencv_bgsegm430d \
    #more lib files
    -lopencv_xobjdetect430d \
    -lopencv_xphoto430d
}

release {
LIBS +=-LE:\\buildsfullsize\\cvbuild\\install\\x64\\vc16\\lib \
    -lopencv_aruco430 \
    -lopencv_bgsegm430 \
    #more lib files
    -lopencv_xobjdetect430 \
    -lopencv_xphoto430 
}
```

Comment: _they seem to give me the same 20fps in release and debug (im testing by checking the fps of my camera video in opencv)_ In general, debug code runs slower than release code because the former is usually augmented with additional checks to make developers life easier. However, if the video provides 20 frames per second and even the debug version is able to run sufficiently fast... What do you expect? If I got you wrong you may [edit] and clarify your question. In general, you may check the performance with _profiling tools_ if in doubt.

Comment: Concerning _profiling tools_: [**google "c++ profiling tools site:stackoverflow.com"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+profiling+tools+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Concerning _opencv c++ works fine but im checking if its running the opencv release and debug lib files._: You may try [**Dependency Walker**](https://www.dependencywalker.com/). It's my tool of choice to check what DLLs a Windows application "pulls" in.